# How can I create a key value pair for such format?

Tags: python, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

So I am working with Spark RDDs. I have a tab separated file with the following format

```
Actor1   Movie1
         Movie2
         Movie3

Actor2   Movie4
         Movie5
         Movie6
```

And I want to create Key value pairs, where key is the actor, and values are the movies in which the actor was casted. How can I do that using Scala or Python? I am able to read the text file and split the lines from tabs, such as the following but I have no idea how to form the key value pairs.

```
 lines = sc.textFile("file")
 tuples = lines.map(lambda x: x.split("\t"));
 # how do I create key value pairs???
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, or at least shouldn't. The whole point of spark is that different lines may be processed in parallel; if the first two lines run on one cluster node and the second two lines run on a different cluster node, there's no way for the second node to know that Movie3 goes with Actor1.

You could use `mapPartitions` with a function that takes lines as an `Iterator` and uses a `var` to keep track of the "current" Actor. If you're careful about how your input text file is split, you might not lose any data. But I urge you to find a better input format instead.

Comment: The input file is given as it is, I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to solve a similar kind of problem .. what is the conclusion on this question ? does work ? how to use mapPartion to solve this kind of problems?